# locking screen orientation on mobile browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, screen, mobile-safari, screen-orientation

I create a web page(chrome & safari) for mobiles (iphone & android), I want to lock the screen orientation in portrait mode.

Unlike mobile apps,there is no manifest file and activity as it a web page.

How to lock the orientation in mobiles using technologies (css/javascript/bootstrap/jquery) or any other?

Comment: What language that you use?

Answer (score 11):

I use a manifest file for my web app, which locks orientation for Chrome on my Android. For whatever reason, Safari gives their users the "right" to do this, but not the designers of the web app... Sort of feels like copyright infringement or something! ;) Don't get me started on Safari's disgraceful rewriting/rendering of input buttons!...

Anyways, back to the answer.

1) Include a link to your manifest within the `head` section of your page:

`<link rel="manifest" href="http://yoursite.com/manifest.json">`

2) Create your manifest file, "manifest.json"

```
{
"name":"A nice title for your web app",
"display":"standalone",
"orientation":"portrait"
}
```

3) Read more about manifests [HERE](http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/manifest/)

Comment: what do you mean with standalone?

Comment: See the link in the post, or visit https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen for a bit more info on the topic.

Comment: Apple and their iOS Safari is PWA cancer

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect even on Android.

Answer (score 5):

From my tests, assigning the screen.lockOrientation ( every browser versions ) to a var throw an illegal invocation error. Just use  wind.screen.orientation.lock('landscape');  . It

EDIT: You can't use lock orientation on safari, cause it doesn't support fullscreen api at the moment http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen . The lock orientation API NEED a fullscreen page to work. In Chrome, the window.screen.orientation.lock return a promise. So, AFTER you go fullscreen with the page, you can do something like this :

```
var lockFunction =  window.screen.orientation.lock;
if (lockFunction.call(window.screen.orientation, 'landscape')) {
           console.log('Orientation locked')
        } else {
            console.error('There was a problem in locking the orientation')
        }
```

However, the lock orientation and fullscreen API are still experimental, not all browsers supports it.

Comment: I think your answer is incomplete

Comment: Maybe the answer was incomplete, but i dont't think the other 2 were complete: just cut and paste from MDN. At least i gave a working implementation of the API.

Comment: This works on Chrome for Android! The numpty that downvoted is a party pooper.

Answer (score 2):

The **lockOrientation** method locks the screen into the specified orientation.

```
lockedAllowed = window.screen.lockOrientation(orientation);
```

From the following code, you can check that **orientation is locked or not**.

```
var lockOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;

if (lockOrientation("landscape-primary")) {
   // orientation was locked
} else {
  // orientation lock failed
}
```

see the following link, you will get idea from this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.lockOrientation

Comment: the given code doesn't seem to work on chrome and safari.Is there any other solution.Thank you

Comment: `lockOrientation` is deprecated, you should use `screen.orientation.lock()` instead

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
  console.log("The orientation of the screen is: " + screen.orientation);
});

and 

screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
```

Following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation

Comment: :thanks for the help.but the above code doesn,t seem to work on chrome.Is there any other solution?

Comment: try body[orient="landscape"] or body[orient="portrait"]